# Concept of deprecated methods and iOS deployment target

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Can anyone please explain the concept of iOS deployment target build setting in iOS project. I have an application which I needed to support from iOS 4.3 up till iOS 6.0. What should be my iOS deployment target?

When I set this to 4.3 it compiles well but if I change it to 6.0 I see lot of compilation warnings for deprecated methods. What is the ideal way of handling this. Shall I remove all the warnings I see on iOS 6.0 keeping in mind that it still supports 4.3 targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment target is the earliest version of iOS that can run your application. So if you want to support from iOS 4.3 to 6.0 you should have *Deployment target* set to 4.3 and *Base SDK* to iOS 6.0.

Deprecated methods are methods that will no longer be supported in future versions of the SDK. These methods give a warning and could lead to unsafe code, because there is a better approach. Its encouraged not to use them. Sometimes, you need to run one method or other depending on the version of the OS, but this becomes out of the scope of the question ;-)

As a conclusion, the ideal depends on your product, but keep in mind that iOS users adopt new versions of the OS quite early. So I would go from iOS 5.0 to 6.0, but this is my personal opinion ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The deployment target is how you specify the minimum required iOS version for your app. If you need to support iOS 4.3 and above, your deployment target should be iOS 4.3.

A "deprecated method" is one that has been marked for removal from the SDK at some point in the future. Depending on the API in question, you may have no choice but to continue using them as long as you have to target iOS 4.3.

Consider raising your required iOS version as soon as is reasonably possible so that you can take advantage of the newest APIs. This will give the best overall compatibility and performance on the largest number of recent iOS devices.